ROS 1 Controllers for tricycle drive
Hi I am new to ROS and I have created a URDF for a tricycle robot. I now wanted to control the robot using a tricycle drive controller but I do not see any packages for the same. Are there any references for the controller? I want to input the robot velocities and get the wheel velocities (for the front wheel) as an output (steering speed and the angular speed). Thanks!
